# Why does 0.5 rounded with MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero result in 0?

Tags: .net, mono, rounding, unity-game-engine

Why does this result in 0 and not 1?

```
Math.Round(0.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Here's an example: http://ideone.com/ayMVO

Comment: are you sure you aren't applying something else to this. my tests resulted in 1 being the result of this calculation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, with issues like that, it's because the number cannot be represented exactly in IEEE754 - it's most likely it's being converted to 0.4999999999... or something like that which would round to zero.

However, 0.5 (1/2) *is* exactly representable in IEEE754 so that's not the case here.

It's possible that the compiler made a mistake in converting the text to a number but I would think that unlikely. In fact, when I compile and run the following in VC#2010:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine (Math.Round (0.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        }
    }
}
```

I get the output of `1` as expected.

So I don't think your question is quite complete. Now it may be that your *actual* situation doesn't use a hard-coded value of `0.5` but instead uses a variable which you *believe* to be 0.5.

My answer to that would be that, while it may be *close* to 0.5 (certainly close enough that a simple `WriteLine` of it might output 0.5), it's probably a touch *below* 0.5, which would cause my comments in the first paragraph above to once again kick in.

---

Based on your link, it appears that Mono 2.8 may have a bug. I'd suggesting seeking support from the developers (or just raising a bug report) [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Support).

Actually, having tried it locally with gmcs 2.6.7, it's definitely a bug. That exact code compiled okay but generates 0 rather than 1. A [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3661) has been raised, and I've added my own information to it.

Comment: Is it possible to round a number to the nearest whole number consistently rounding up for `.5`?

Comment: Yes, use the Microsoft product, or file a bug report on Mono :-)

Comment: The former isn't an option as I'm writing code for the Unity3d framework which uses Mono, but if it's indeed a bug, I'll try and pester someone about it :)

Comment: @Acorn, a cursory search of the bug DB turned up nothing. You can file a report at http://www.mono-project.com/Support

Answer (score 0):

This also returns 1.0 for me when I debugged it.

```
Math.Round(0.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: That's not correct, AwayFromZero is a different algorithm than banker's rounding. Banker's rounding is ToEven.

Comment: @WaynnLue my mistake, I removed the original post. I ran the code and I got 1.0

Answer (score 0):

0.5 is a double.

If you do

```
Math.Round(0.5M, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

It will work as expected