# C# - Math.Round(double d, 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero) Produces to many decimals

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I'm doing a little coding for the hell of it and I've come across a problem! Now, this may be a duplicate question, but I can for the love of me not find anyone else with the same problem, so here goes;

I am trying to round a Random generated double, to 2 decimal points. And this works as expected most of the time. However, everyonce in a while, my code produces doubles with up to 10+ decimals, which is really annoying, seeing as the values are displayed in a DataGrid in WPF, and the DataGrid, just resizes to fit the number. The code I am using to generate my doubles:

```
double d = rand.NextDouble() + .5; // I have more of these, differing from + .5 to + 2
```

And then to round it of, I use:

```
Math.Round(d, 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

And most of the time, it works flawlessly, but every so often, it produces numbers like:

```
0.639999999999999
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
So I don't do it exactly as I said. If this has anything to do with why it won't work, I would like to know, but the way I actually create my doubles is;

```
Math.Round(rand.NextDouble() + .5, 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

However I can't see why it would make a difference, if a create a double first, and then round it, or if I just insta-round a newly created double.

Edit 2:
By request, I am posting my DataGrid code. XAML and codebehind looks as such:
XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="marketDataGrid" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="13,225,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Height="204" Width="303" 
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              SelectionMode="Extended"
              IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="MarketRow_DoubleClick" ></EventSetter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

And the code behind for double click events:

```
private void MarketRow_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
        Company c = (Company)marketDataGrid.SelectedItem;
        BuyWindow bw = new BuyWindow(c, pc, this);
        bw.Show();
    }
```

And the code where I add the list of objects

```
 marketDataGrid.ItemsSource = cc.GetCList();
 marketDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Please let me know if you need more. I could upload the entire project somewhere if you wanna look through it all. I would probably be a little embarrassed to do so, as my code is not exactly pretty all the way through.

It may be a typo on my behalf... But I don't think so. I've looked through the solution pretty carefully.

Comment: "// I have more of these, differing from + .5 to + 2" what does that mean exactly? Do you know which one yields such a :`0.639999999999999` output?

Comment: @qiTsuk what is the value of d when `0.639999999999999` this occurs

Comment: Probably because 0.639999999999999 is the closest number to 0.64 that you can represent with IEEE754. If you use `decimal` it should work as you expect

Comment: @MongZhu - What I mean is, that I produce more random doubles where I add a number to it. Seeing as I do the rounding instantly, I don't actually know what d is when the weird rounding happens. I actually do `Math.Round(rand.NextDouble() + .5, 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Comment: where do you store the result of Math.Round(rand.NextDouble() + .5, 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero)? How do you get the output?

Comment: @MatteoUmili I thought so at first too, but it seems to work for me: `d = 0.64d; Console.WriteLine(d);` outputs `0.64`. qiTusk: no offence, just to be sure: do you _assign_ the result of `Math.Round` to `d` or not? You don't show it in your examples. `Math.Round` does not _change_ `d`, it _returns_ the rounded value.

Comment: There are some threads that might help explain this phenomenon, although not exactly duplicates (imho) [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221205/why-does-system-midpointrounding-awayfromzero-not-round-up-in-this-instance) / [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475448/why-does-0-5-rounded-with-midpointrounding-awayfromzero-result-in-0)

Comment: Tried to reproduce this by generating random numbers in a loop and printing any that results in a long string when converted with `ToString()`. Could not find any examples of this happening at all so I don't think that `Round()` is the problem here.

Comment: @RenéVogt I don't assign it to d, I assign it to another empty double called P... So it goes, `private double P; P = Math.Round(rand.NextDouble() + .5, 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Comment: @qiTsuk I have tested this with ` for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000000; i++){ double d = obj.NextDouble() + .5;var um = Math.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);int length = um.ToString().Length;
if (length > 4){}` and could not reproduce

Comment: I also was not able to reproduce the issue in a console application. Perhaps it is caused by _WPF_ (it's a matter of the value being displayed wrong rather than being wrong itself), so I'd suggest [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)ing the source value (or trying to pinpoint the problematic value some other way).

Comment: @Grx70 - I will try that. And I will return if I figure this out.

Comment: Seems to work as expected, ran several times.


  var d = new Random();

            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
               textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text += Math.Round(d.NextDouble() + .5, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) + Environment.NewLine;
            }

Comment: This one is intriguing, please could you post your datagrid code? Like the others here I have run this without being able to replicate. I have also put the results into a datagrid which also doesn't seem to produce the issue, despite putting many millions of rows into the grid.

Answer (score 0):

By the very nature of [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), out of the 101 mathematical values `0.50, 0.51, 0.52, ..., 1.48, 1.49, 1.50`, there are only **5** (namely `0.50` and `0.75` and `1.00` and `1.25` and `1.50`) that can be represented exactly. All the others (`0.51` and `0.52` etc.) will have an internal representation that differs from the mathematically exact two-decimal value.

(You could use an `int` (with values from `50` through `150`) or a [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal) (from `0.50m` through `1.50m`) to avoid this.)

For this reason, it all comes down to how the internal `double` representation is **formatted** into a displayable string of digits and separator symbols.

You say you use [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/) but do not supply further information about the formatting used in the grid. I am not sure if WPF uses `double.ToString` or some other mechanism.

At the time the question was asked, both .NET (called .NET Core at the time) and .NET Framework used a non-IEEE-compliant implementation of `double.ToString`. Under this nonstandard implementation, using the format string `"G17"` could in some cases reveal a part of the representation inaccuracy. For example, `(0.51).ToString("G17")` gave the string `"0.51000000000000001"` (the decimal separator `.` depends on current `CultureInfo` with this overload). However, something like `(0.62).ToString("G17")` gave just `"0.62"` because 17 significant figures are not enough in this case to reveal the discrepancy.

Starting in 2019 (.NET Core 3.0), there are significant differences between the formatting in .NET and that in .NET Framework. The former now uses a more compliant algorithm, while the latter still uses the old nonstandard implementation.

In .NET after 2019, you can demand many more digits than 17. For example, `(0.51).ToString("G40")` now gives `"0.5100000000000000088817841970012523233891"`, and `(0.62).ToString("G40")` gives `"0.6199999999999999955591079014993738383055"`. You can read more about these breaking changes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/corefx#floating-point-formatting-and-parsing-behavior-changed). There is a link to a blog post [Floating-Point Parsing and Formatting improvements in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) by Tanner Gooding.

As I said, I am not sure if WPF in 2016 (so before 2019) used .NET's nonstandard formatting logic, or had its own. Maybe it has its own. It would take a WPF expert (not me), and possibly some additional information about your settings, to answer.